# .net app not working

Tags: .net

I have an application that requires .net framework. I have it installed, and also checked in the "turn on windows features". But when I try to run the app, the process runs for a couple of second in the task bar, but the application never starts. 
I have windows 7. And I have installed .net framework 2, 3, 3.5 and 4. 
The application is also very small, particular to the company, so therefore it is not available online, and people dont know about it.
What could be going wrong.
Also, it is working on other PCs.

Comment: Absolutely anything, the program could be opening, crashing immediately and then closing without ever telling you.

Comment: What sort of application, and which version of .NET was it built again? We really don't have enough information here...

Comment: it uses .net framework 3.5. I have it checked in my "turn on windows features", however, when I run net framework clean up tool, it doesnt show me 3.4, neither 3 nor 2. I dont know whats wrong. Please help!!

Comment: Sounds like a user permission issue...

Comment: Have you tried consulting the author of said application?

Comment: So then I unintalled .net 4.0. Then by running the application, it would give me the error that says "to run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of .NET framework: v4.0.30319..."

Comment: So I install it, but still back to the earlier problem.
Also, I checked the event viewer. It had an error saying, "The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception info: System.Runtime.InterlopService.COMException..."

Answer (score 0):

Check the Application event logs. .NET might dump something in there. Also use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), if you don't have the source code that may help you spot whether it's a file/network/permission error.